# How to send mail using Office365 REST API?

Tags: php, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

I am working with Office365 REST API. I am facing problem in sending email. I can't find any help in core php.

I am able to access mails and attachments but unable to send a mail. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
// SEND MAIL FUNCTION

if(isset($_GET['send_email'])){
$resuu = "okay";
$resuu = SendMail();
echo $resuu;

}
function SendMail(){

$userID = get_user_id();

$headers = array(
                            "User-Agent: php-tutorial/1.0",         
                            "Authorization: Bearer ".token()->access_token, 
                            "Accept: application/json",             
                            "client-request-id: ".makeGuid(), 
                            "return-client-request-id: true", 
                            "X-AnchorMailbox: ". get_user_email()
);
$newmail = '{
"Message": {
  "Subject": "Sending 1st email dont fails plz?",
  "Body": {
  "ContentType": "Text",
  "Content": "The new cafeteria is open."
   },
 "ToRecipients": [
   {
      "EmailAddress": {
         "Address": "chxanu123@gmail.com"
       }
     }
    ]
   },
  "SaveToSentItems": "true"
}';
    $outlookApiUrl = $_SESSION["api_url"] . "/Users('$userID')/sendmail";
    $response = runCurl($outlookApiUrl, $newmail, $headers);
    return $response;
    //Session[api_url] contains $_SESSION["api_url"] = //"https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0";
    }

 ?>
```

Here is the run curl method I used to access mails

```
function runCurl($url, $post = null, $headers = null) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $post == null ? 0 : 1);
 if($post != null) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
 }
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  if($headers != null) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 }
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($ch);
 if($http_code >= 400) {
     echo "Error executing request to Office365 api with error 
 code=$http_code<br/><br/>\n\n";
     //echo "<pre>"; print_r($response); echo "</pre>";
     die();
 }
return $response;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

What error response are you getting?  Do you have HTTP response headers, or is it failing before it gets off your box?

One thing with REST - no need for the X-AnchorMailbox.  That is an EWS concept.  The target mailbox is always in the URL and our front end servers will ignore what you put in the X-AnchorMailbox header for the REST API.  But that wouldn't be the cause of your failure.

Comment: Sterling 
The problem was i didnt made message array properly, then i needed to jsonencode it before passing it.

Comment: $userID = get_user_id();
 $request = array(
"Message" => array(
"Subject" =>$_POST["subject"],
"ToRecipients" => $to,
"Attachments" => $attachments,
"Body" => array(
 "ContentType" => "HTML",
 "Content" => utf8_encode($_POST["message"])
)
 )
    );

    $request = json_encode($request);
    $headers = array(
        "User-Agent: php-tutorial/1.0",
        "Authorization: Bearer ".token()->access_token,
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Content-Length: ". strlen($request)
    );

Comment: @ZeeshanCh If you managed to self-solve, please do not post your solution as a comment.  Please post your working code as an answer and then accept it by awarding your own answer the green tick.